# Getting ids of leaf vertices in gremlin query

Tags: gremlin

I'm still pretty new to Gremlin... I have a graph with self-loop edges, and I need a gremlin query to find the leaf vertices. These would be vertices that either have no outgoing edges or whose edges only loop back to themselves.
Is there a simple query that could provide the ids of these vertices?

Answer (score 0):

To find vertices without out-going edges (ignoring self-referencing edges) you would do:

```
g.V().as("a").            /* vertices                 */
  not(out().              /* without out-going edges  */
        where(neq("a")))  /* ignoring self-references */
```